# Using sed to find and append multiple files with multiple lines?

Tags: sed

Hi I'm trying to append a few lines of codes to a couple thousand html files in a directory (and sub-directories). What I'm trying to do is add xxx lines of code to all html files following the  tag. I've tried to explore sed but I'm having issues with having the / sign inside the search and adding the several lines of codes to the sed command.

I'm thinking of adding the lines I want to add in a txt file and use sed to place all content in that txt file after the  tag.
 Much appreciate any help.

Say sample.html contains this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<h1>Title</h1>
<body>
etc
```

I want to add this after the `</h1>` element:

```
<script>
etc.
</script>
<iframe>
</iframe>
```

to Produce this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<h1>Title</h1>
<script>
etc.
</script>
<iframe>
</iframe>
<body>
etc
```

Comment: Please provide a sample piece of html and text and show us what you want the result to be.

Comment: placed it up. hope it can help clarify my problem.

Comment: First, the `<h1>` tag needs to be inside `<body>`. Next, you say "add this after the element" -- after *which* element? H1? Please be specific.

Comment: oh the yntax of the html code doesn't matter. All my html code is proper, i was just careless in the example.  I essentially want to add my code after the </h1> tag. There is only 1 in all of my html files and I want to add the same code in all files (an iframe and javascript).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to place the text after the H1 end tag, and that end tag `enter code here`:

```
sed -i '/<\/h1>/r new_text.html' sample.html
```

Comment: this worked but I somehow getting an error with my html pages when i open them of the server. all my pages have become forbidden. I think it has to do with how sed is outputing the data it read in.

Comment: If you have shell access, check the file permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

Content of **script.sed**

```
/<\/h1>/ {
        a\
<script>\
etc.\
</script>\
<iframe>\
</iframe>
}
```

Run it like:

```
sed -i -f script.sed sample.html
```