# Is it possible to add information to the head tag of multiple HTML files, without going into each file manually?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

Basically, I have a stylesheet I need to add to a LOT of HTML files. It would take so long to add it to each one manually that it wouldn't even be worth it. Is there any script or application I can use to help me with this, or any tricks in HTML I can take advantage of? Thanks.

Comment: If it is really going to time consuming to hand edit all these files, it may be worth investigating a script based solution. If you are on a Mac Os or any unix you can [``sed``](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) or a related program (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6836822/1048479) SO post). I'm sure there are Microsoft Powershell alternatives as well. If you give some more details on the # of files, and your OS I can try to write one for you.

Answer (score 2):

Most IDE's have a function called 'find and replace'. I work with Netbeans, but I imagine almost every IDE can do this, perhaps even a decent text editor may be sufficient. Usually you can find it in the 'edit' menu somewhere.

You could search for `</head>` and replace it with `<link href=.../></head>` or something similar.

Ususally you can tell the replace function which folder it should search in, and even wich file types to check for. Should be easy and done in a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Do these HTML pages share some resource? You can consider 2 options:

1 - Make a script to insert those stylesheets to the HTML files head automatically or;

2 - Insert the stylesheet once in an resource(Require the file for an script i.e) already shared by those files;

Comment: I'm not sure I actually have the knowledge to make a script for this sort of thing if I'm honest, as I don't have any proper experience programming...

Comment: Do your HTML files have some base where they've been developed? I mean, there is a certain script or stylesheet whose ALL those HTML files are already importing?

Comment: There is a Javascript file that is being imported by all of them, yes.

Comment: Add the following line of code to that file: 

$('head').append("<style rel='stylesheet' href='yourfolder/yourfile.css'/>'")

Answer (score 1):

use php `include();` and paste it on top of files. wont take you more than 5sec per page.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this fairly easily using a good text editor like [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) or TextMate (Mac OS X). Here are instructions for how to do this in Sublime Text 2:

1. Open Sublime Text 2
2. Create A New Window (File » New Window)
3. Make sure the Side Bar is visible (View » Side Bar…)
4. Drag and drop the HTML files (you want to add the stylesheet to) onto the Side Bar
5. Find » Find in Files… (Note the mini find-replace dialog at the bottom of the window)
6. Search: `</head>`
7. Where: (Clear this field so it will look in: Open files and folders)
8. Replace: `<link href=.../></head>` (Hat tip to: @PeterVR)
9. Click **Replace**
10. Confirm dialog and be sure to save all your files!

Good luck!

Comment: If I were to drag and drop entire folders full of both HTML and a variety of other files into the sidebar, would there be a way to auto detect the HTML files and only add the code to them?

And thanks, this is a very useful tip :D

Comment: Yup! The **Where:** field is basically a filter, so you could clear the field (so that it looks at "Open files and folders"), then add: `*.html` so that it will only apply the Find and Replace to `.html` files. You could also add other extensions like this: `*.html, *.php, *.inc` if you want. By the way, instead of clicking **Replace**, you can click **Find** to preview which files it will affect.